# Is there a search app for Android with no-tracking privacy policy?

Tags: search, search-history

On the desktop I use [ixquick](https://ixquick.com/) to avoid Google tracking my searches. But on Android it is even worse since I am logged in and Google can track everything I do. Is there an app for ixquick or for another search engine that does not log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DuckDuckGo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duckduckgo.mobile.android)

Answer (score 1):

I've had pretty good luck with duckduckgo for Android. You can also set your browser home page to it or startpage or ixquick.